# Display special character in json log with syslog-ng

Tags: c, json, syslog-ng

I used to handle my log with Syslog. I am currently trying to switch to syslog-ng and also to update the format of my log to follow JSON standard.

First I define a syslog-ng configuration file :

```
@version: 3.2X

filter f_middleware {
    facility("local1");
};

template t_json_filetemplate {
    template("{\"timestamp\":\"${ISODATE}\",${MESSAGE}\n");
};

source s_kernel {
    file("/proc/kmsg" program_override("kernel"));
};

source s_middleware {
    unix-stream("/dev/log");
};

destination d_kernel {
    file("/data/logs/kern.log");
};

destination d_middleware {
    file("/data/logs/middleware.log", template(t_json_filetemplate));
};

log {
    source(s_kernel);
    destination(d_kernel);
};

log {
    source(s_middleware);
    filter(f_middleware);
    destination(d_middleware);
};
```

In my middleware c code, I

```
openlog("middleware", 0, LOG_LOCAL1);
```

I format my log with macro in my code to handle the expected json format from my custom server:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#define _PRINT_DEBUG(M, ...)                            \
    do {                                    \
        syslog(LOG_DEBUG, "\"category\":\"%s\",\"level\":\"DEBUG\",\"message\":\"" M "%s\"}\n", __DIR__, __VA_ARGS__); \
    } while (0)
#else
```

The problem is if I tried to display a file content with Syslog, the end of the message
is truncated. it is working correctly for other types of message of course.

Here for example I try to print the content of the file **/proc/cmdline**

```
   {"timestamp":"2020-04-20T16:55:50+02:00","category":"XXX_MANAGER","level":"DEBUG","message":"root ptr : root=/dev/xxx
```

The '**}**' is missing at the end. It is because there is a '**\n**' at the end of the file ?

I also tried to add some stuff about escaping in my config file :

```
destination d_middleware {
        file("/data/logs/middleware.log", template("{\"timestamp\":\"${ISODATE}\",${MESSAGE}\n") template-escape(no));
```

No better result...

A guess that I am using syslog-ng in a bad way...

More complete explanation of the problem after some investigation
https://lists.balabit.hu/pipermail/syslog-ng/2020-April/025836.html

Comment: C can write Json with one of several libraries.  Use one. Don't try to write json "by hand".

Comment: I am on an embedded system. I don't want to have to add an extra library just to format a JSON if it is possible. And Syslog-ng seems to support JSON format in the documentation. So it is weird that is there not a clean way to encode properly a string as JSON right?

Answer (score 0):

> It is because there is a '\n' at the end of the file?

Yes, `unix-stream()` uses `\n` to separate messages. You should escape your message in your middleware.

---

Alternatively, you can use, for example, `unix-dgram()` with `flags(no-parse)`. You may need to send your data to a `SOCK_DGRAM` socket in that case, but on Linux, `syslog()` is actually dgram-based.

From the glibc manual:

> openlog may or may not open the /dev/log socket, depending on option. If it does, it tries to open it and connect it as a stream socket. If that doesn’t work, it tries to open it and connect it as a datagram socket.

Comment: I will try to use the flags(no-parse). I already tried to use it but without success. I have always syntax error.  The syntax of the config file is really weird and complex even there is a ton of doc and example.

Comment: My suggestion would be to use unix-dgram() instead of unix-stream(), if it's possible in your environment, because unix-dgram() is not newline-separated.

Escaping/removing newlines from your syslog messages would be even better, because multi-line messages are not really widespread.

Comment: I run the test with unix dgram. At least I am able to fix the issue with \n now. My new result :
{"timestamp":"2020-04-22T16:33:49+02:00","category":"XXX","level":"DEBUG","message":"Check on singleton : Success.
"}
{"timestamp":"2020-04-22T16:33:49+02:00","category":"XXX","level":"DEBUG","message":"Board config : xxx"}

Comment: Looks good. syslog-ng also has a proper json-parser() and $(format-json) template function in case you want to make sure your JSON is valid.

Comment: it is really safe to use unix-dgram ? Documentation is saying that I can loose some message when the system is overloaded **: The unix-stream() and unix-dgram() drivers open an AF_UNIX socket and start listening on it for messages. The unix-stream() driver is primarily used on Linux and uses SOCK_STREAM semantics (connection oriented, no messages are lost), while unix-dgram() is used on BSDs and uses SOCK_DGRAM semantics: this may result in lost local messages if the system is overloaded.**

Comment: You can read more about this here: https://github.com/syslog-ng/syslog-ng/issues/2934#issuecomment-533603489

On Linux, you should not experience message loss with unix-dgram().

Comment: Now that I am able to fix the \n issue. The last one is about escaping. I was able to making work the escaping feature of syslog-ng. But the problem is that syslog-ng is escaping everything. But I just want to escape stuff in message key value. And not escaping category and level  key value. I tried to looking for solution in filter feature. But I cannot do that. At the end I will have perhaps to do it myself manually but its really sad